# Isolation capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I am creating a 24V switched source. The GND of the transformer primary must be isolated from the GND of the transformer secondary, I read that a capacitor must be used to isolate the GND's. Does anyone know how I can calculate the capacitance value for this capacitor?

[image]

Comment: A capacitor won't isolate grounds that are connected. You need to think about your question a bit more because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floating secondary with high [CM noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_interference) from leakage capacitance across the transformer can interfere with high impedance circuits or long transmission lines (ethernet).

So one method of reducing this noise and still avoid ground fault line voltages is to determine a [shunt capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunt_(electrical)#Electrical_noise_bypass) to bypass coupling capacitance leakage from primary to secondary.

The [IEC/UL limit on safety leakage current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_safety_testing#Leakage_Current_Test_(Line_Leakage_Test)) ~ 0.21mA (including Line filter*) at line volt/freq. using L=N to Gnd measurements at line voltage.

You want to shunt the CM noise at >[SMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) f + harmonics so the transformer coupling capacitance* must be low in order to minimize the shunt cap to gnd yet give high [CMRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_rejection_ratio).

So effectively line voltage is isolated but [RF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) noise on secondary DC Common Mode(CM) is shunted to earth ground.

Can you compute this?  What do you get?  *make some assumptions

There is a simple method for a ["ballpark value".](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ballpark)
 (hint) Ohm's Law for Caps. I(f)=V(f)/Zc(f)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMQ0Ax.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Many of the terms cited I had never seen. I'm an engineering student but I know how to do projects now. I'll study what you said to determine my need.

Comment: I'll add some essential links then